# How to bulk mail-enable contacts from AD in Exchange 2007?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, contacts

We have several thousand 'contacts' setup in AD already for a faxing system. We're migrating to an online fax provider that uses e-mail rather than plain old telephone. So, we've bulk edited all the AD records so that the 'mail' attribute is populated with the right e-mail address in the right format.

Now, how do we enable these contacts within Exchange 2007? I've looked through http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684891.aspx but that only seems to talk about manually editing the CSV output to specify the external addresses. AD already knows the external e-mail addresses - I just need the info in Exchange!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2006/12/bulk-mailbox-enabling-users-exchange-shell.html

```
get-user –organizationalUnit people | where-object {$_.RecipientType –eq “User” -and $_.department –eq “Sales”} | Enable-Mailbox –Database “EXCHANGE1\Mailbox Database” | get-mailbox | select name,windowsemailaddress,database
```

Have a read through of the first link - very helpful.

http://exchangepedia.com/2006/11/exchange-server-2007-bulk-creation-of-mailboxes-using-exchange-management-shell.html

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - I'm not looking to setup mailboxes, but mail-enabled contacts. Thanks, thought!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [ExchMbx](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/exchmbx/index.htm) but is untested with Exchange 2007

Answer (score 1):

Check out ADModify.  It allows bulk change to AD attributes including exchange attributes.

[Howto article for modifying Exchange attributes with ADModify](http://www.msexchange.org/articles/ADModify-Change-Exchange-Specific-AD-User-Attributes.html)